# What is the prefered way to factor out behavior

Tags: scala, coding-style, refactoring

Let's say I have a couple of classes internally sharing some behavior like

```
def workspace = Plugin.get.reallyGet.getWorkspace
```

What is the best way to factor it out? I see two possibilities which can be used equivalently in the using code.

```
trait WorkspaceProvider {
  def workspace = Plugin.get.reallyGet.getWorkspace
}
```

and mix it in or

```
object WorkspaceProvider {
  def workspace = Plugin.get.reallyGet.getWorkspace
}
```

and import it. What would you prefer and why?

Answer (score 4):

The former is preferable. The latter is essentially static, un-mockable and hard to test.

Since you're thinking in terms of coupling (a very good thing) you should familiarize yourself with the Cake Pattern (it is much covered on 'Net, starting with the [paper](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.pdf) in which the concept was first described).

Comment: Also I recommend this post http://www.precog.com/blog-precog-2/entry/existential-types-ftw and this video http://marakana.com/s/post/1399/cake_pattern_bakery_from_the_black_lagoon_daniel_spiewak_ne_scala_video by Daniel Spiewak

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko Nice talk.

Comment: @RandallSchulz Cake pattern is nice but it's pretty heavy-weight.

Comment: The url for the existential-types-ftw article is no longer valid because precog site is no more.  But the author very kindly provided me with this archived version: https://github.com/precog/staticsite/blob/master/contents/blog/Existential-Types-FTW/index.md

Answer (score 2):

You can define both:

```
trait WorkspaceProvider {
  def workspace = Plugin.get.reallyGet.getWorkspace
}

object WorkspaceProvider extends WorkspaceProvider
```

The first form is more flexible. For example, it allows to be mixed at instanciation:

```
trait Foo { this:WorkspaceProvider =>
   def bar = workspace.doSomethingRelevantHere
}

val myFoo = new Foo with WorkspaceProvider
```

But the second form is more convenient if you just want to use the `workspace` method. For example in tests, prototypes, etc.

**EDIT:**

For a little more elaboration about this approach, check out ["Selfless Trait Pattern"](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/selfless_trait_pattern.html), where Bill Venners shows how it is implemented in ScalaTest.

Comment: I checked the link. One of the issues seems to be name conflicts and that's one of the things that initially came to my mind too. Providing both options seems like a nice decision on the providing side.